# Authentication over Kerberos in ActiveMQ (embedded in Spring Boot)

Tags: authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, activemq-classic, kerberos

I'm looking for a solution from title.
I have ActiveMQ broker embedded in Spring Boot application.
What I want to do is to authenticate some domain technical users (dedicated for some applications) over Kerberos. I know there is solution for LDAP authentication but I need Kerberos authentication.
Is there any possibility to do so?
Is there any possibility to do so using spring-security?
Could you explain how to do this?
I'm actualy stuck on this.

Thanks for all your answers!

Comment: Have you cheecked http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-kerberos/ ?

Comment: Yes, we have already using it for http/https but what I need is to authenticate over tcp protocol because I'll have some systems connecting directly to Queues in broker via tcp protocol.